# Does .war file has all the dependency jars for deployment in a container?

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, war

I developed a simple RESTful webservice using Jersesy, the reference implementation of JAR-RS.

I created a maven project, and in pom.xml I specified all the dependencies. I used eclipse IDE. It works fine.

Now, I wanted to deploy the application as .war file in apache tomcat. For this, i first used the "export" option in eclipse (Right click on project -> export -> war) and generated the .war file.

Now, my doubt is:

Since the code that I wrote depends on many .jar's (for example, jersey jar's etc), will the exported .war file have all the needed .jar's to run in a  container in a different physical server (but same software i.e. apache tomcat).

In my code I am using jdbc driver's as well (which I specified as dependency in pom.xml), do I need to worry to have all these jar's present in a physically different server where i intend to deploy the generated .war?

I am not clear on this, any help would be great help in clearing this basic doubt.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you simply do a maven build ?

Comment: I can, however I want to clear my doubts, the doubts which I ignored and creating mess for big projects!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specifie your jar as maven dependencies they will be on WEB-INF/lib directory of your war (except if you set scope to provided).

By the way it's more easier to create your war file by maven with this command

```
mvn clean package
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it did clear my understanding, need to look more on how this works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

A .war, .jar, and .ear file is really just a zip file with a different extension. You can inspect the contents of the file easily by viewing/extracting it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, however I wanted to check what the behaviour is. I did check the contents and it seems there were all the needed .jars, the things i wanted is to clear the basics.